# Dismiss custom dialog from Async Task in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, dialog, dismiss

I have a custom dialog and when a button pressed it executes an async task. What i want is to dismiss dialog onpostexecute of async task. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the code you have. Without that, all we can say is, `dialog.dismiss()`

Comment: thanks i ve found a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `Async` as inner class dismiss it directly using `dialog.dismiss()` where the `dialog` is declared as class instance variable. If not, pass it via `async constructor` and then `dismiss` it on `onPostExecute`.
Usually what I would do is: create the dialog on `onPreExecute` and then `dismiss` it on `onPostExecute`, but it also depends on your need, where you are declaring it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dismiss dialog before AsynTask finished, you can call `dialog.dismiss()` in `onProgressUpdate()` method of AsynTask in moment what you need. This function called in UI thread, so you will not have problems with that.

Additional info about `onProgressUpdate()` function can find here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html